# Unity3D ReorderableList fields display below the box

Tags: unity3d-editor

I am trying to create a Reorderable List, but I am having an Issue using EditorGUILayout with it. If I use EditorGUI It works fine, but then the fields are static in size (unless I manually calculate the size every time).

Here is what I am doing:

```
    list = new ReorderableList(serializedObject, serializedObject.FindProperty("groupSettings"), true, true, true, true);

    list.drawElementCallback = (Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused) => {
        SerializedProperty element = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(element.FindPropertyRelative("poolGroupName"), GUIContent.none);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(element.FindPropertyRelative("minPoolSize"), GUIContent.none);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(element.FindPropertyRelative("maxPoolSize"), GUIContent.none);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(element.FindPropertyRelative("prewarmCount"), GUIContent.none);
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(element.FindPropertyRelative("prewarmObject"), GUIContent.none);
        }
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    };
```

When I use EditorGUILayout, the controls display below the Reorderable list.  I can still swap order, but the contents is always displayed below the list.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see at callback parameter. There is Rect parameter which is area to display GUI elements. You cannot use GUILayout or EditorGUILayout. You should calculate position by yourself.

```
list.drawElementCallback = (Rect rect, int index, bool isActive, bool isFocused) => {
    SerializedProperty element = list.serializedProperty.GetArrayElementAtIndex(index);

    float gap = 10f;
    float numColumns = 5f;
    float width = (rect.width - (numColumns - 1) * gap) / numColumns;
    rect.height = 16f;
    rect.width = width;

    EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property.FindPropertyRelative("poolGroupName"));
    rect.x += rect.width + gap;

    EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property.FindPropertyRelative("minPoolSize"));
    rect.x += rect.width + gap;

    EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property.FindPropertyRelative("maxPoolSize"));

    rect.x += rect.width + gap;
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property.FindPropertyRelative("prewarmCount"));

    rect.x += rect.width + gap;
    EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property.FindPropertyRelative("prewarmObject"));
};
```